# Generate random name to struct element in C

Tags: c

I want to generate random names to book.author and book.title
but when i print nothing shows.

```
typedef struct Book{
char title[20];
char author[20];
int pages;
double price;
}Book;

int randInit(int min, int max){
return min + rand()%(max -min +1);
}

void rand_Init_Book(Book *b){
int len =randInit(10,20); 
for(int i =1 ; i < 1;i++)
{
    b->title[i] = (char)randInit('a','z');   
}
len =randInit(10,20);
for(int i =1 ; i < randInit(10,20);i++)
{
    b->author[i] = randInit('a','z');
}
b->pages = randInit(5,2000);
b->price = (100 + rand()%(10000-100))/100.;    

}
```

The names will not be actual names, just some string. When I exit the loop and i want to print it says that the string is empty. I've tried with strcpy whit another string but the same result.

Comment: Where is the actual printing?

Comment: What do you think `for(int i =1 ; i < 1;i++)` will do?

Comment: Aside: in this `for(int i =1 ; i < randInit(10,20);i++)` did you mean to *precalculate* the loop end condition? You'll get a new limit recalculated during the iteration.

Comment: I have function that prints the struct.

Comment: Yes this function is for the size of the name, between 10 and 20 chars

Comment: Another aside: don't forget to nul-terminate the strings. I hope your random length allows for this.

Comment: After you fix the errant for loops, you'll also need to null-terminate the strings you've populated.

Comment: for(int i =1 ; i < **1**;i++) is that a letter l or a one? It's a one.

Comment: So *both* the loops should be `for(int i =0 ; i < len; i++)` and the `len` might be one-too-big.

Comment: thats for(int i =1 ; i < 1;i++) is meant to be i < len ;

Comment: how to null-terminate the string ?

Comment: Start the iteration at 0 not 1. Write `b->title[len] = '\0';` after. But `len` can be out-of bounds, so the arrays need to be one longer, or the random assignment one shorter.

Comment: yes i think it works when i start from 0, idk why i started with 1. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

**No iteration**

`for(int i =1 ; i < 1;i++)` never iterates as `i < 1` is immediately false.

**Code fails to index properly**

Array's are zero-based indexed.

```
// for(int i =1 ; i < randInit(10,20);i++)
for(int i = 1; i < randInit(10,20); i++)
```

**Excessive length**

`char author[20];` can hold a *string* up to 19 characters + the final *null character*.

```
// len =randInit(10,20);
len = randInit(10, 20 - 1);
```

**No need to repeatedly find a random length**

```
// for(int i =1 ; i < randInit(10,20);i++)
for(int i = 0; i < len;i++)
```

**Missing *null character***

A *string* needs a final *null character*.

---

**Tips**

- Improve formatting - use an auto formatter.
- Avoid naked magic numbers like `10`.

Example:

```
#define NAME_LENGTH_MIN 10
void rand_Init_Book(Book *b) {
  int len = randInit(NAME_LENGTH_MIN, sizeof b->title - 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    b->title[i] = (char) randInit('a', 'z');
  }
  b->title[len] = '\0';

  len = randInit(NAME_LENGTH_MIN, sizeof b->author - 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    b->author[i] = (char) randInit('a', 'z');
  }
  b->author[len] = '\0';

  b->pages = randInit(5, 2000);
  b->price = (100 + rand() % (10000 - 100)) / 100.0;
}
```